# Java, StanfordNLP Parser: How to stop tokenizing angle brackets as markup / tokenize angle brackets as punctuation?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm parsing a dataset in which people are using angle brackets simply as punctuation, and never (ever) does actual markup occur.

Is there a means of changing the parser's functionality such that instead of calling

```
"<snickers in background>"
```

a single token, we can get

```
"<", "snickers", etc?
```

It seems like a fairly straightforward issue, but I haven't been able to find a simple fix in the docs or from looking through code.

Thanks in advance!

PS Are there other characters which behave in this way that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a simple way to do this. There are some options for customizing the treatment of quotes, dashes, and bracket escaping in the tokenizer, but overall the tokenizer has many heuristic rules, most of which cannot be changed at the command-line.

You have two main options:

- Write your own implementation of Tokenizer and TokenizerFactory, and then ask for it to be used instead of the default PTBTokenizer, asking for it with the command-line flag `-tokenizerFactory`
- Tokenize the input in advance of parsing, and then give the flag `-tokenized`

Of course, to the extent that regular tokens aren't tokenized as expected by Penn Treebank conventions, parsing accuracy will tend to suffer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the heads up on that. We may end up just replacing <>s with {}s or something. Do you happen to know if there's a way to get the post-processed (penn'd/americanized/etc) text as a string? I have the offsets as part of the tokenized output, but no single string to which to apply them. I can just rebuild the string, probably, based on offsets and just assuming space delineation, but if there were a way to get that data from the parser itself that'd be great.